# Vue + Express +GCloud routing breaks in App Service

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a Vue3 + Express + Okta app. It works perfectly fine on local, but once I deploy it to Google Cloud's App Service I can only load the main page. Any navigation gives me 404.
I assume I am doing something dumb, but I've tried all I can think about to no avail. Help please?

Here's my router (I removed extra routes):

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import AppHeader from "./layout/AppHeader";
import AppFooter from "./layout/AppFooter";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import ListEpisodes from "./views/ListEpisodes.vue";
import { LoginCallback, navigationGuard } from '@okta/okta-vue';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      components: {
        default: Home,
        footer: AppFooter,
        header: AppHeader
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/episodes",
      name: "episodes",
      components: {
        header: AppHeader,
        default: ListEpisodes,
        footer: AppFooter
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login/callback',
      component: LoginCallback
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach(navigationGuard);
export default router;
```

To deploy to GCP, I run `npm run build` for the frontend, then copy dist/ to my express app's static folder, then "gcloud app deploy".

The routing worked fine in GCP before I moved from vue2 to vue3 to integrate with okta. The extra stuff was history: createWebHistory() and router.beforeEach(navigationGuard);

Any ideas what can that be?

createWebHistory() was originally createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL). I thought maybe there's an issue there, so I tried creating .env file with BASE_URL=https://my_domain.

Then I removed the parameter - no difference on local, still didn't work on GCP.

Tried removing nocache from the express app as well, as that was another thing I changed before redeploying from working (vue2 many changes ago) version.

UPD: here's my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs16
service: default
instance_class: F2
```

Comment: Add your the contents of your app.yaml file to the question

Comment: done, just a standard one, haven't changed that between when it worked and when it stopped

Comment: Another thing to note, my APIs work fine on the same URL. When I run locally, apis are on port 3000, and app is on port 8080. I guess, on GCP they are all on the same default https port.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still don't know what is happening, but I found another way to do this: deploying API and frontend separately and then setting up the dispatch rules to connect Vue app to the backend.

I have used this guide with a few changes: https://medium.com/@rgoyard/how-to-deploy-a-single-page-application-and-its-backend-to-google-app-engine-353ff93bd38c

1. in vue.config.js for the Vue app remove/comment out the proxy redirecting to your API:

```
devServer: {
  //   proxy: {
  //     '^/api': {
  //       target: 'http://localhost:3000',
  //       changeOrigin: true
  //     },
  //   }
}
```

2. Create `frontend.yaml` in the frontend dir, don't set any handlers:

```
runtime: nodejs18
service: default
```

3. Deploy frontend: `gcloud app deploy frontend.yaml`
4. Create `api.yaml` in the API dir:

```
runtime: nodejs18
service: api
```

4. Deploy API: `gcloud app deploy api.yaml`
5. Create `dispatch.yaml` in the root dir (or anywhere, really):

```
dispatch:
  - url: '*/api/*'
  service: api
```

6. Deploy dispatch rules: `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml`